# Не работает isset PHP 7

Tags: php

После обновления убунты, в PHP 7 перестала работать функция isset в определённом случае:

```
class Foo
{
    protected function get_xx()
    {
        return array('name' => 'Vasya');
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == 'xx') {
            return $this->get_xx();
        }
    }

    public function something()
    {
        if (isset($this->xx['name'])) {
            echo 'Good!';
        }
    }
}
```

Так вот, функция isset в методе something возвращает false;
При этом если вызвать `isset($this->get_xx()['name'])` то вернёт true;

До обновления убунты всё работало нормально, и в пхп 5.4 работает нормально.

В чём может быть причина?
Спасибо!

Comment: У меня печатает "good". Версия PHP 7.0.9-pl1-gentoo

Comment: Скрипт из вашего определения класса, плюс `(new Foo)->something();`. 7.0.0, 7.0.5, 7.0.7, 7.0.8, имеющиеся у меня под рукой, равно как и 5.4.45, 5.6.22 исполняют идентично - выводят "Good!"

Comment: вам нужно метод [__isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) реализовать, чтобы работало в php7. Никак ссылку не найду где это изменение описывалось...

Comment: [habr:Обновление PHP до 7.0.6 может «сломать» ваш код](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248721/)

Comment: Хм, в PHP 5.6 метод __ISSET игнорируется, а вот в 7.08 уже используется, до этого стояло 7.02 вроде бы.